# how to write mokito junit for a method containging stored procedure call

Tags: java, stored-procedures, junit, mockito

mokito junit for stored procedure call

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName(PROCEDURE_NAME).returningResultSet(
        PROCEDURE_OUTPUT, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(PolicyDetailsResultSetVO.class));
SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue(PROCEDURE_INPUT,
        policyDetailsRequest.getPolicyNumber());
Map<String, Object> result = jdbcCall.execute(in);
System.out.println("result: " + result);
List<PolicyDetailsResultSetVO> policyDetailsResults = (List) result.get(PROCEDURE_OUTPUT);
```

remaing code is to convert this policyDetailsResults required response object format.

I want to write juint for this I tried the below code .But I am getting datasource was null error

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Error retrieving database meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: DatabaseMetaData returned by Connection [connectionMock] was null
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataProviderFactory.createMetaDataProvider(CallMetaDataProviderFactory.java:142)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext.initializeMetaData(CallMetaDataContext.java:243)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.compileInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:304)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.compile(AbstractJdbcCall.java:289)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.checkCompiled(AbstractJdbcCall.java:349)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:364)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:197)
    at com.cts.common.dao.impl.PolicyDetailsFetchDaoImpl.fetchPolicyDetails(PolicyDetailsFetchDaoImpl.java:59)
    at com.cts.common.dao.impl.PolicyDetailsFetchDaoImplTest.fetchPolicyDetailsTest(PolicyDetailsFetchDaoImplTest.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: DatabaseMetaData returned by Connection [connectionMock] was null
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataProviderFactory.createMetaDataProvider(CallMetaDataProviderFactory.java:73)
    ... 36 more
```

test code

```
    assertNotNull(dataSourceMock);

     when(dataSourceMock.getConnection()).thenReturn(connectionMock);
    // when(connectionMock.getMetaData()).thenReturn(databaseMetaDataMock);

    when(jdbcCallMock.execute(Mockito.any(SqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(resultSetMock);
    // when((List)resultSetMock.get("P_POLICYDETAIL")).thenReturn(policyDetailsResults);
    // when((List) result.get("P_POLICYDETAIL")).thenReturn(policyDetailsResults);

    when(policyDetailsFetchDaoImpl.fetchPolicyDetails(policyDetailsRequest)).thenReturn(policyDetailResponse);
```

Comment: On debugging I am getting exception at Map result = jdbcCall.execute(in);

Comment: why did comment the following : // when(connectionMock.getMetaData()).thenReturn(databaseMetaDataMock);

Comment: one adding that also I am getting exception - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Statement specified.